# Determine if N is a pseudoprime / strong pseudoprime

Tags: prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

How can I conclude from the following table whether N=15841 is a pseudoprime and/or strong pseudoprime for the bases a=2, a=145, and a=789?

Given is that 15840 = 2^5 * 495

[image]

So far I know that a composite number N is called a pseudoprime for the base a if

a^(N-1) = 1 (mod N)

and a strong pseudoprime if

a^((N-1)/2) = (a/N) (mod N)

However that would result in a huge number such as a^15840 which is impossible to calculate. I suppose I should use the fact that 15840 = 2^5 * 495 but I'm not sure how?

EDIT:
I'm guessing N would be pseudoprime for a base if there's at least one 1, but I'm not entirely sure when it's a strong pseudoprime.

Comment: For a strong pseudoprime, you need a $1$ in the row with the odd exponent, or a $-1$ (here $15840$) in any of the rows.

Comment: Wait. Are you sure about the definition of "strong pseudoprime". I know $a^{(N-1)/2} \equiv \bigl(\frac{a}{N}\bigr) \pmod{N}$ (for composite $N$) as "Euler pseudoprime", a _strong pseudoprime_ being a composite $N$ such that $N$ divides one of the factors in $$a^{N-1} - 1 = (a^k - 1)\prod_{\sigma = 0}^{s-1} (a^{2^{\sigma}k} + 1)$$ where $N-1 = 2^sk$ with an odd $k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. Is this always the case (for every N and base)? And what if there are multiple odd exponents? Should they all be 1 for it to be a strong pseudoprime?

Comment: @DanielFischer I found the definition here https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1446788700019364 however I'm not entirely sure if these formulas should be used at all with this exercise.

Comment: It depends on the definition of "strong pseudoprime". The usual one is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime), and the provided data fits with that definition, not so well with [Euler pseudoprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_pseudoprime). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime) for various classes of pseudoprimes.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know, it's not mentioned which kind of strong pseudoprime. Would it help if I told you the solution? 2 and 145 are strong pseudoprimes and 789 isn't.

Comment: That rules out Lehmer's definition, since $\bigl(\frac{789}{15841}\bigr) = 1$, hence $15841$ is an Euler pseudoprime (also Euler–Jacobi pseudoprime) to base $789$. But it's not a strong (Fermat) pseudoprime to base $789$.

Comment: Note that when Lehmer wrote that paper some 45 years ago, the terminology was not yet as established as it is nowadays (and even nowadays it's by no means uniform), so his use of "strong pseudoprime" in a different sense than is now usual shouldn't be (too) surprising.

Comment: @DanielFischer So knowing the correct definition... is your first comment still the correct way to find if it's a strong pseudoprime from the table?

Comment: The first comment is the way for the now common definition as on wikipedia. A $1$ in the first row says $N \mid a^k - 1$, and a $-1$ ($15840$) in any of the rows says $N \mid a^{2^{\sigma}k} + 1$ (where $\sigma + 1$ is the number of the row, counted from the top).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103529/discussion-between-sj19-and-daniel-fischer).